# How can I calculate the accuracy for my Custom Vision Model?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

On the Microsoft Custom Vision Portal I only have the Precision and Recall results, how can I generate the  True positive (TP), False positive (FP), True negative (TN)  and False negative (FN) from the same images that the service used to corss validate itself to then get the accurancy?

tks